# Sharepoint Online not able to Upload twbx files(files related tableau)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

we recently migrated 2013 site to sharepoint online using metalogix tool, in one of 2013 site there exists a document library which has .twbx files (which are related to tableau software)

when we migrated that document library is not migrating the .twbx files to the online document library

is there any way we can upload these files to online library?? or is this type of files not supported in sharepoint online??

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no unsupported file types in sharepoint online and O365. Please check for
    [Supported Fileformats in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3)

We can upload .twbx files. Can you able to upload it manually?